# Adding TypeScript definitions for wrapped classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-server

I'm using a package called [`react-server`](https://react-server.io/) that can take *any* class and will add methods to it at runtime.  It expects to have the class that it wraps to have an interface like

```
interface {
    getElements(): Array<React.Component>
}
```

and it will add methods to the class like `getRequest()`, which can be referenced from inside the class as well.

Imagine a page class like:

```
class SimplePage {
  getElements() {
    // Right now, this wouldn't compile, because this.getRequest() is
    // not an available method.
    const request: Request = this.getRequest();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Given that `this.getRequest()` doesn't actually exist at compile time, and that `react-server` doesn't actually provide any real classes or interfaces that I can reference from my definition file, is there any way that I can create a definition that I can use that calls out that something is, in fact, a `Page` type and has these methods available to it?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to provide these in a definition file (`.d.ts`) somewhere so that I can reference them in any app that uses `react-server`.  I'd also love to do this without being forced to cast `this` to something else every time I wanted to reference the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options that I can think of.
Given the following interface:

```
interface ExtendedPage {
    getRequest(): Request;
}
```

(1) The [this parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters):

```
class SimplePage {
    getElements(this: SimplePage & ExtendedPage) {
        const request: Request = this.getRequest();
        // ...
    }
}
```

(2) Implement the interface with stand-in properties ([like with mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)):

```
class SimplePage implements ExtendedPage {
    getElements() {
        const request: Request = this.getRequest();
        // ...
    }

    getRequest: () => Request;
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can declare a class and extend it:

```
declare class ExtendedPage {
    getRequest(): Request;
}

class SimplePage extends ExtendedPage {
    ...
}
```

Comment: These are good options. I was hoping for something like a class I could extend that didn't map to a real type when compiled to JS (e.g. `Page` extends `RSPage` or something, where `RSPage` is defined somewhere else and then gets dropped during compilation), but these will work if nothing like that exists.

Comment: You can actually use a declared class, check my revised answer